# Is my analysis of quantum numbers describing the ground state of At correct?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrons, electronic-configuration

Which series of quantum numbers describes the highest (energy) occupied orbital in a ground state of **At** atom?

a) n = 6, l = 0 
b) n = 6, l = 2 
c) n = 5, l = 2 
d) n = 4, l = 3 
**e) n = 6, l = 1**

According to my teacher, the answer is e.

My analysis:

- The electron configuration of At atom:

$$\begin{aligned}1s^22s^22p^63s^23p^6\ce{3d^10}4s^24p^64\ce{d^10}5s^25p^64\ce{f^14}\ce{5d^10}6s^26p^5
\end{aligned}$$

Knowing for levels 0,1,2,3 correspond to s,p,d,f respectively we can say that:

a) $$\begin{aligned}6s^2\end{aligned}$$
b) $$\begin{aligned}Nothing \end{aligned}$$
c) $$\begin{aligned}\ce{5d^10}\end{aligned}$$
d) $$\begin{aligned}\ce{4f^14}\end{aligned}$$
e) $$\begin{aligned}\ce{6p^5}\end{aligned}$$

What I thought here first is that d is the answer since 4f<sup>14</sup> has the largest number of electrons, and thus will occupy the highest energy around.

Then I saw on another question that the orbitals are filled so that the ones of lowest energy are filled first.

$$1s < 2s < 2p < 3s < 3p < 4s < 3d < 4p < 5s < 4d < 5p < 6s < 4f < 5d < 6p < 7s ...$$

In this case, e is the answer since 6p<sup>5</sup> has the highest energy regardless of the number of electrons it is holding?

Comment: Your second way of thinking about it is correct.  The number of electrons in the orbital is not the determining factor here.  Well written question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes , there is another name for it **(n+l) rule** or *Aufbau principle*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle

Even though it is not correct to check this rule at such higher values of Z where the trend sometimes changes due to very less differnce between higher values of shell and orbitals .But if you are a beginner you should not heed to this statement.